# What is the most efficient implementation of the min-k-cut algorithm?

Tags: optimization, graph-theory, extreme-value

Simple question, I'd like to apply min-k-cut algorithm on a graph to partition the graph in k clusters by minimizing the sum of edges cut during the formation of clusters.

In my case I already know k (it would be an input). Bonus point if you know of a library in R or Python that implements the algorithm.